# How do we list all nodes having 0 or more specific connection types along with the connection count data on gremlin tinkerpop

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I will appreciate if you can advice on a single gremlin query that will give me the list of all nodes and the counts of a specific connection type for each node.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What do you mean by connection type ? Is that an edge label ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get all the edges for each node and group them by node then this should do it :

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern();
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal();
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.E().group().by(inV());
==>[v[2]:[e[7][1-knows->2]],v[3]:[e[9][1-created->3],e[11][4-created->3],e[12][6-created->3]],v[4]:[e[8][1-knows->4]],v[5]:[e[10][4-created->5]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the number of labels of all incident edges:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().project("v","labels").by().by(bothE().groupCount().by(label))
==>[v:v[1],labels:[created:1,knows:2]]
==>[v:v[2],labels:[knows:1]]
==>[v:v[3],labels:[created:3]]
==>[v:v[4],labels:[created:2,knows:1]]
==>[v:v[5],labels:[created:1]]
==>[v:v[6],labels:[created:1]]
```